# Indexing pandas dataframe when column names are integers

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I don't seem to be able to subset data using integer column names using loc command

```
# 6*4 data set with column names as x,y,8,9

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(6,4)),
                  index=('a','b','c','1','2','3'),
                  columns=['x','y', 8, 9])

df2 = df.loc[:,:'x']
df3 = df.loc[:,:'8']
```

df2 works but df3 throws error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do either:

```py
df3 = df.loc[:,8]
```

To get only column `8`

Or:

```py
df3 = df.loc[:,df.columns[:list(df.columns).index(8)+1]]
```

To get all columns until column `8` (inclusive - remove `+1` to get exclusive).

Comment: I agree. You can also do `df3 = df[list(df.columns)[:2]]`. `df.loc[:]` is superfluous because it targets all the indexes so you might as well just target the columns. Cheers!

Comment: Not to get only column '8' but upto (not including column '8'). There is supposed to be a colon in from of 'x' in the previous command

Comment: @PetarLuketina Basically my issue is `df2 = df.loc[:,:'x'] ` gives everything upto 'x' . I can t do the same for integer column names